# Respecting associations with rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

We are using rails_admin plug in to manage back end for a classroom. There is an admin(Coordinator) and several moderators(Teaching assistants). The admin and moderators should be able to add students to the database. Each student is associated with a moderator(TA). When a moderator clicks to view the students the rails_admin renders all the students in the database. How can we restrict rails_admin to show only those students whose TA is the moderator who is logged in? Admin should be able to see all the students in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails_admin has this capability built in. You've got a couple of options as per their [wiki page](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping):

- Editing the `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` configuration file as per [this section](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping#scoping-ordering-and-limiting-associable-records-in-filtering-selectsmultiselects)
- Or my personal preference, using CanCan or CanCanCan as per [this section](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping#restricting-records-through-authorization)

Happy to help if you run in to more specific issues.

Good luck!

*Edit: Bonus link for CanCan & rails_admin, again [on their wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan)*